# Observer only receives value from one next call

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Inspired by the example at [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) (Parent and children communicate via a service) I implemented an observer/observable pattern to notify my navigation component weither the user is authenticated. The problem is that the navigation component only receives a notification when the user logout.

My authentication service looks like:

```
export class AuthenticationService {

  private isAuthenticatedSource = new Subject<boolean>();

  isAuthenticated$ = this.isAuthenticatedSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http : AuthHttp) {}

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    ...
    this.isAuthenticatedSource.next(true);
    ...
  }

  logout() {
    ...
    this.isAuthenticatedSource.next(false);
    ...
  }

}
```

I have ensured that both calls (login and logout) are made and no errors are thrown. My navigation component looks like:

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  private subscription: Subscription;

  isAuthenticated: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService,
              private router: Router) {
    this.isAuthenticated = authService.isAuthenticated();
  }

  logout(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(["Authentication", "Login"]);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.authService.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(
      value => console.log("updated to:", value)
    );
  }

}
```

The console should log "Updated to: true" when logging in and "Updated to: false" when logging out. The problem is that it is only displaying a message when logging out. Clearly the observer does not receive the value (true) when logging in. Hope you can help explain why this is happening.

**Update**

The call to login is now included below. It is called from my `LoginComponent` when a user submits a (login) form. `LoginComponent` looks like:

```
export class LoginComponent {

  public email : string;
  public password : string;
  public errors : any;
  public next : any;

  constructor(private authService : AuthenticationService,
              private router : Router,
              private params : RouteParams) {
    // default to navigate to dashboard on successfull login
    let next = this.params.get("next") || "/Dashboard";
    this.next =  [next];
  }

  login(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
                      .subscribe(
                        data => this.router.navigate(this.next),
                        errors => this.errors = errors);
  }

}
```

The corresponding template has a single call to login: `<form (submit)="login($event)">`. login is not called other places in the application.

Comment: You can already subscribe in the constructor, no need to wait for `ngOnInit()` if the code doesn't depend on inputs being updated. Maybe the event was already sent before the `NavigationComponent` subscribed. I think you need a `BehaviorSubject` to get the last value immediately after subscribe.

Comment: I don't see the call to `login` in your code- are you sure you're calling that _after_ you've subscribed to the Subject? A Subject will only send out events to subscribers after subscription - you possibly want a different type of Subject, perhaps `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Tried BehaviorSubject and it did not change anything. I will also move the subscribe call to the constructor, but the situation is still the same. @tddmonkey Yes I am sure. login is called when a user clicks a button - long after NavigationComponent has subscribed to the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not excactly sure why it works, but setting `isAuthenticatedSource` as a static variable fixes the problem. Will have to research some more to understand why. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you called login. However, I've worked up an example that shows that calling login on the service before the UI subscribes reproduces your observation, that the UI is not updated. See the authService.login() call in the AppComponent constructor has no effect on the UI. This is because the subscribe happened later in ngOnInit. Hope this is useful.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fteTLPCJUucCVKdVzJuP

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit { 

  @Output subscribe: string;
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private authService: AuthenticationService;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.subscribe = 'not set';
    this.authService = authService;

    authService.login('john', 'password'); // has no affect on UI since login happens before subscribe in ngOnInit 
  }

  login() {
    this.authService.login('john', 'password');
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.authService.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(
      //value => console.log("updated to:", value)
      value => this.subscribe = '' + value;
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice example. The problem still persists though. I have updated my question to also include the call to login. As you can see, it is happening after `NavigationComponent` subscribes.